# Calender Datepicker in appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I have to select the desired date on theDatapicker but unable to do so.

What I did, made a function which will store all the web elements in a list and traverse through the desired input(date/yr/month) by their index values and perform an action on it.
In my case, I have only class & index value through which I would play with them.
This wouldn’t work for me.

Code that i have tried:

```
MobileElement list = driver.findElement(loc); 
try{ 
     list.findElement(MobileBy .AndroidUIAutomator(“new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(” + “new UiSelector().text(” val “));”));
    //Also did that approach: 2. 
     “new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().text(”.val")).flingForward()"));
} catch(Exception e){ 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      System.out.println(“Cannot scroll further”); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Code:
MobileElement list = driver.findElement(loc);
try{
list.findElement(MobileBy
.AndroidUIAutomator(“new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(”
+ “new UiSelector().text(” val “));”));}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println(“Cannot scroll further”);

Also did that approach:
2. “new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().text(”.val")).flingForward()"));

Comment: refer this blog for reference https://selenium-automation-help.blogspot.com/p/appium.html